# Copal Shutter FStop Label Replacement?

Tags: old-lenses, large-format

I recently received a lens in a Copal #0 shutter that is missing the fstop label. It looks like that label is made of metal and screwed in, so I should be able to just get a new label and put it on.

[image]

What is that part called? Where would I get a replacement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is called a "shutter aperture scale" and they are very expensive. They are also dependent on the lens.

- https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/92894-REG/Schneider_SAS_Shutter_Aperture_Scales.html
- https://www.skgrimes.com/services/large-format-photography-repair-services
- https://www.photrio.com/forum/threads/source-for-copal-f-stop-scales.43080/print